# Attempt to read past end-of-file at address

Tags: formatting, fortran, unexpectendoffile

writing a very simple read file in Fortran 95. The file has only three numbers in it, every time I run the code, the .exe file says "`error: attempt to read end-of-file at address`", any clues why this keeps happening?

The code is :

```
program readdata

implicit none

!Delcaration of variables

real :: x,y,z

!Main part

open (10, file='C:\Users\matth\OneDrive\Documents\Tutorialcode\array.txt',ACCESS='SEQUENTIAL', STATUS='OLD', FORM='FORMATTED')

read (10, *) x, y, z

print *,x,y,z

close (10)

end program readdata
```

Comment: You'd also have to post the _file_.

Comment: Test the following: in a terminal, go to the director "C:\Users\matth\OneDrive\Documents\Tutorialcode". Change the "open" statement to only use "array.txt". Test again. There might be an issue with the path to the file (backslashes instead of slashes, etc).

Comment: Also, please provide the compiler, the command invoked to compile the code and the command used to execute the code.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. When debugging, please compile your code with debugging flags enabled (for example `gfortran -g -Wall -fcheck=all`) and post the *complete* error output here. Do not just select a sentence, but tell us all the details. We certainly need to see your input file here. I also suggest to use forward slashes for your paths, they do work on Windows.

Comment: Hello everybody. The input file was a simple .txt file with the numbers: 1.00, 2.00, 3.00 in the file in a list. The compiler I am working with is checkmate as it’s part of the Silverfrost free download so that’s what I’m using. The code seems to compile good, builds and links the only problem arises when executing. I don’t have access to the whole warning code right now but will tomorrow, Hope this makes sense? Everything from compiling to executing done with silverfrost free download

Comment: The input file is a simple text file with the numbers: 1.00, 2.00, 3.00 in it.

Comment: Attempt to read past end-of-file at address 1c0086e1
Within file readdata2.exe
in READDATA2 in line 6, at address e8
RAX = 0000000000000039   RBX = 0000000000000039   RCX = 0000000000000039   RDX = 0000000000000000
RBP = 000000001c000000   RSI = 0000000000000039   RDI = 00000000001fa0b0   RSP = 000000000240f9d0
R8  = 00000000000000a1   R9  = 00000000000000a1   R10 = 000000000000009e   R11 = 000000000240f6e0
R12 = 0000000000000000   R13 = 0000000000000003   R14 = 00000000004050a0   R15 = 0000000000405098
1c0086e1) int9

Comment: The compiler is CHECKMATE and SLINK is the linker

Comment: Error message:***57 Attempt to read past end-of-file at location main -  in file readdata2.f95 at line 6 [+00b0]                           line 6: read(10,*) a,b,c

Answer (score 0):

I have loaded your code into my Eclipse IDE, using GNU Fortran.

I confirm that the code compiles, without error or warning, and runs as advertised.

With an array.txt file of:

```
1.00, 2.00, 3.00
```

I get output:

```
1.00, 2.00, 3.00
```

With an empty file I get:

```
At line 13 of file ../readdata.f90 (unit = 10, file = 'C:\Users\franc\array.txt')
Fortran runtime error: End of file

Error termination. Backtrace:

Could not print backtrace: libbacktrace could not find executable to open
#0  0xffffffff
#1  0xffffffff
#2  0xffffffff
#3  0xffffffff
#4  0xffffffff
#5  0xffffffff
#6  0xffffffff
#7  0xffffffff
#8  0xffffffff
#9  0xffffffff
#10  0xffffffff
#11  0xffffffff
#12  0xffffffff
#13  0xffffffff
#14  0xffffffff
```

So, my suspicion is over whether your file is missing some values.

Please also see:

[Fortran 90 - Attempt to read past end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003610/fortran-90-attempt-to-read-past-end-of-file)